GRPC microservice probe failing in google cloud run
The startup probe for my grpc spring boot microservice fails.
This is defined in my terraform file as follows
startup_probe = {
    grpc = {
      port  = 9090
      service = "grpc.health.v1.Health/Check"
    }
  }

grpcurl -plaintext localhost:9090 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check

{
  "status": "SERVING"
}

I expected the probe to pass and my application to no longer be red
As you can see from the logs below. The server starts correctly it is just the probe that fails
2024-09-25 22:25:56.164 CEST
22:25:56,164 [34mINFO [0;39m [main] [36mAbstractGrpcServerFactory[0;39m - Registered gRPC service: envoy.service.ext_proc.v3.ExternalProcessor, bean: externalProcessorService, class: net.payback.globalapi.requestprocessor.application.service.ExternalProcessorService
2024-09-25 22:25:56.164 CEST
22:25:56,164 [34mINFO [0;39m [main] [36mAbstractGrpcServerFactory[0;39m - Registered gRPC service: grpc.health.v1.Health, bean: grpcHealthService, class: io.grpc.protobuf.services.HealthServiceImpl
2024-09-25 22:25:56.164 CEST
22:25:56,165 [34mINFO [0;39m [main] [36mAbstractGrpcServerFactory[0;39m - Registered gRPC service: grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection, bean: protoReflectionService, class: io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService
2024-09-25 22:25:56.226 CEST
22:25:56,226 [34mINFO [0;39m [main] [36mGrpcServerLifecycle[0;39m - gRPC Server started, listening on address: *, port: 9090

